# Manhua where a scientist makes a system, the main character is a suitable host

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manhua where a scientist makes a system but dies due to a monster attack. The system goes off searching for a suitable host, which is the main character. Later on in the story he fights an alien fish in order to save the city, but everyone thinks he is a murderer because he killed the ones who were infected by the monster. He learns martial arts from the system; he learned spear arts and even healing skills. But he isn't the only one who knows martial arts in his world most people have talent, and some don't. Some become famous for helping others and the others become villains.

All I know is that mc learns skills and wears this mask:

[image]

Comment: That mask appears to be part of a collection of "kawaii" (cute) masks that are commercially available (e.g. not merchandise from a manga/anime); https://www.amazon.com/Aniwon-Kawaii-Muffle-Anti-Dust-Kaomoji/dp/B078S5YT6R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on this, the querent located the work in question, and left a comment on my post, "The Interceptor Cross System" by ChiChi and Qi Guai (still looking for a non-infringing link):

[image: front cover of The Interceptor Cross System]

> The Interceptor Cross System ” is a Chinese story, telling about the adventure of Song Cheng. He used to be a useless guy, working for a hopeless job. All his life is all about eating and playing boring games. One day, a powerful crystal bringing the power of breaking the limit of normal people, combined into Song Cheng body. Everything has changed, Song Cheng starts his new journey with his new power….
> Crossing Man

This description is fairly consistent over several sites. I read the first several panels, and indeed it starts with a man in a lab designing the system (which shows up as a dark shape in a glass container), then cutting to an explosion at the facility, then the protagonist with the system narrating that it has found the perfect host.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... other than the mask, I'd say you might be referring to *[Solo Leveling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solo_Leveling)*

[image: Front cover of Solo Leveling]

> In a world where hunters — humans who possess magical abilities — must battle deadly monsters to protect the human race from certain annihilation, a notoriously weak hunter named Sung Jinwoo finds himself in a seemingly endless struggle for survival. One day, after narrowly surviving an overwhelmingly powerful double dungeon (dungeons are places where specific monsters reside, they can be entered through portals and vary in strength thus given rankings the same as hunters)that nearly wipes out his entire party, a mysterious program called the System chooses him as its sole player and in turn, gives him the extremely rare ability to level up in strength, possibly beyond any known limits. Jinwoo then sets out on a journey as he fights against all kinds of enemies, both man and monster, to discover the secrets of the dungeons and the true source of his powers.

It is indeed revealed that the Architect designed the System, but that it escaped and infected [Sung Jin-woo](https://hero.fandom.com/wiki/Sung_Jin-Woo).

> The true purpose for the Architect creating the System was to find a host strong enough to become the vessel for the Shadow Monarch, which slowly modifies his body using Ashborn's power. Following his completion of the Final Trial of the Architect and attaining the original Shadow Monarch's Black Heart, Jin-Woo then became the Shadow Monarch, the original monarch was not reborn. After his heart was pierced and encountering Ashborn, he left all his powers to Jin-Woo, which resulted releasing the System, granting him access to all his power.

Not matching, the Architect is not dead at the start of the manga, and eventually becomes an antagonist when it turns out that the Shadow Monarch plans to transfer its power entirely rather than to continue funneling it through Jin-Woo in a way that the Architect can exploit.

Comment: no i read solo leveling already 